# Retrieving all PK and FK

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, primary-key, pgadmin

I have a big database that I need to extract all primary keys and foreign keys from each table.

I have pgAdmin III.

Is there a way to do this automatically and not go over each table manually?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use the function [`pg_get_constraintdef(constraint_oid)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) in a query like the following:

```
SELECT conrelid::regclass AS table_from
     , conname
     , pg_get_constraintdef(oid)
FROM   pg_constraint
WHERE  contype IN ('f', 'p ')
AND    connamespace = 'public'::regnamespace  -- your schema here
ORDER  BY conrelid::regclass::text, contype DESC;
```

Result:

```
 table_from | conname    | pg_get_constraintdef
------------+------------+----------------------
 tbl        | tbl_pkey   | PRIMARY KEY (tbl_id)
 tbl        | tbl_col_fk | FOREIGN KEY (col) REFERENCES tbl2(col) ON UPDATE CASCADE
...
```

Returns all primary and foreign keys for all tables in the given schema, ordered by tablename, PKs first.

[The manual about **`pg_constraint`**.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html)

[The manual about **object identifier types**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) (`regclass`,`regnamespace`, ...).

Comment: This modified where condition returns any unique constraints as well: `WHERE  contype IN ('f', 'p', 'u')`

Comment: is it possible to get a definition of an index in case `WITH (FILLFACTOR=80)` was provided as well during the definition of the index?

Comment: @arthur: Sure, possible. Those details of a supporting index are not reproduced by `pg_get_constraintdef()` - though they can be provided during the constraint definition. I suggest you create a new question presenting your case. You can always link to this one for context and add a comment here to get my attention.

Answer (score 14):

No need to parse `pg_get_constraintdef()`, just use columns of **`pg_constraint`** table to obtain **other details** ([the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html)).

Here `constraint_type` can be:

- p - **primary key**,
- f - **foreign key**,
- u - **unique**,
- c - **check constraint**,
- x - **exclusion**,
- ...

Based on [Erwin's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/37068/154216):

```
SELECT c.conname                                 AS constraint_name,
   c.contype                                     AS constraint_type,
   sch.nspname                                   AS "self_schema",
   tbl.relname                                   AS "self_table",
   ARRAY_AGG(col.attname ORDER BY u.attposition) AS "self_columns",
   f_sch.nspname                                 AS "foreign_schema",
   f_tbl.relname                                 AS "foreign_table",
   ARRAY_AGG(f_col.attname ORDER BY f_u.attposition) AS "foreign_columns",
   pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid)                   AS definition
FROM pg_constraint c
       LEFT JOIN LATERAL UNNEST(c.conkey) WITH ORDINALITY AS u(attnum, attposition) ON TRUE
       LEFT JOIN LATERAL UNNEST(c.confkey) WITH ORDINALITY AS f_u(attnum, attposition) ON f_u.attposition = u.attposition
       JOIN pg_class tbl ON tbl.oid = c.conrelid
       JOIN pg_namespace sch ON sch.oid = tbl.relnamespace
       LEFT JOIN pg_attribute col ON (col.attrelid = tbl.oid AND col.attnum = u.attnum)
       LEFT JOIN pg_class f_tbl ON f_tbl.oid = c.confrelid
       LEFT JOIN pg_namespace f_sch ON f_sch.oid = f_tbl.relnamespace
       LEFT JOIN pg_attribute f_col ON (f_col.attrelid = f_tbl.oid AND f_col.attnum = f_u.attnum)
GROUP BY constraint_name, constraint_type, "self_schema", "self_table", definition, "foreign_schema", "foreign_table"
ORDER BY "self_schema", "self_table";
```

Results are ordered by `schema` and `table`.

Technical note: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8760419/7573844) about `with ordinality`.

Comment: I wonder how to retrieve the referenced columns plus their table and schema, without having to parse the result of `pg_get_constraintdef()`?

Comment: @Anse updated the answer. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 12):

Based on Erwin solution:

```
SELECT conrelid::regclass AS "FK_Table"
      ,CASE WHEN pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid) LIKE 'FOREIGN KEY %' THEN substring(pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid), 14, position(')' in pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid))-14) END AS "FK_Column"
      ,CASE WHEN pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid) LIKE 'FOREIGN KEY %' THEN substring(pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid), position(' REFERENCES ' in pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid))+12, position('(' in substring(pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid), 14))-position(' REFERENCES ' in pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid))+1) END AS "PK_Table"
      ,CASE WHEN pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid) LIKE 'FOREIGN KEY %' THEN substring(pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid), position('(' in substring(pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid), 14))+14, position(')' in substring(pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid), position('(' in substring(pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid), 14))+14))-1) END AS "PK_Column"
FROM   pg_constraint c
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.connamespace
WHERE  contype IN ('f', 'p ')
AND pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid) LIKE 'FOREIGN KEY %'
ORDER  BY pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid), conrelid::regclass::text, contype DESC;
```

Will return a table of form:

```
| FK_Table | FK_Column | PK_Table | PK_Column |
```

Comment: That is nearly what HeidiSQL would need to retrieve foreign key definitions. Is there a way to do the same more elegant, with less `LIKE`, `SUBSTRING` and `POSITION` calls? I am almost there, but columns are listed twice with [my query](https://github.com/HeidiSQL/HeidiSQL/issues/158#issuecomment-579108560).

Comment: The best and most concise answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Recently had to implement this for a Data Access Layer that builds CRUD utilities based on info schema, ended up going with this.

```
SELECT

    current_schema() AS "schema",
    current_catalog AS "database",
    "pg_constraint".conrelid::regclass::text AS "primary_table_name",
    "pg_constraint".confrelid::regclass::text AS "foreign_table_name",

    (
        string_to_array(
            (
                string_to_array(
                    pg_get_constraintdef("pg_constraint".oid),
                    '('
                )
            )[2],
            ')'
        )
    )[1] AS "foreign_column_name",

    "pg_constraint".conindid::regclass::text AS "constraint_name",

    TRIM((
        string_to_array(
            pg_get_constraintdef("pg_constraint".oid),
            '('
        )
    )[1]) AS "constraint_type",

    pg_get_constraintdef("pg_constraint".oid) AS "constraint_definition"

FROM pg_constraint AS "pg_constraint"

JOIN pg_namespace AS "pg_namespace" ON "pg_namespace".oid = "pg_constraint".connamespace

WHERE

    "pg_constraint".contype IN ( 'f', 'p' )
    AND
    "pg_namespace".nspname = current_schema()
    AND
    "pg_constraint".conrelid::regclass::text IN ('whatever_table_name')
```