# How to list all constraints of a table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

How to list all constraints (Primary key, check, unique mutual exclusive, ..) of a table in PostgreSQL?

Comment: The [query in the link](https://gist.github.com/PickledDragon/dd41f4e72b428175354d) is useful ?

Comment: `\d+ tablename` in psql

Comment: Near duplicate: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36979/retrieving-all-pk-and-fk/37068#37068

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Constraints can be retrieved via [`pg_catalog.pg_constraint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html).

```
SELECT con.*
       FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint con
            INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class rel
                       ON rel.oid = con.conrelid
            INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsp
                       ON nsp.oid = connamespace
       WHERE nsp.nspname = '<schema name>'
             AND rel.relname = '<table name>';
```

Replace `<schema name>` with the name of your schema and `<table name>` with the name of your table.

Comment: Notice that `pg_catalog.pg_constraint` does not contain `NOT NULL` constraints.

Comment: @sticky bit, is there anyway to drop all the constraints identified in a table? using single query? How can I pass this list of constraints as input to `ALTER TABLE <table name>
  DROP CONSTRAINT <conname> CASCADE;?

Comment: What is schema name?

Comment: @nacholibre: The name of the schema of the table.

Comment: @TheGreat Old comment, I know, but this is a hack for lack of a better one: `select concat('alter table ', table_schema, '.', table_name, ' drop constraint ', constraint_name, ';') from information_schema.table_constraints where constraint_name [pattern match];` Just set the query part and copy the result into psql.

Comment: If someone is looking to get not null constraints for a table can use this. `SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE is_nullable = 'NO' and table_name = 'your_table_name';`

Answer (score 51):

In the `psql` command line this information is in the table sheet, obtained with the `\d+` command. `d+` also informs on the `NOT NULL` constraints, something that is not present in the `pg_catalog.pg_constraint` table. An example:

```
# \d+ observations.stream   
                                                  Table "observations.stream"
 Column |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target |                 Description                 
--------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+---------------------------------------------
 id     | integer           |           | not null |         | plain    |              | 
 name   | character varying |           | not null |         | extended |              | This should be a table in the import schema
 min_id | integer           |           | not null |         | plain    |              | 
 about  | character varying |           | not null |         | extended |              | 
Indexes:
    "stream_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "stream_name_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (name)
Check constraints:
    "stream_id_check" CHECK (id > 0)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "profile" CONSTRAINT "profile_id_stream_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (id_stream) REFERENCES stream(id)
```

The caveat here is that you do not get the names of all the constraints this way.

Comment: I see constraint names in your posted output.

Answer (score 6):

Here is PostgreSQL specific answer. It will retrieve all columns and their relationship as well:

```
select *FROM (
from (
    select
        pgc.contype as constraint_type,
        ccu.table_schema as table_schema,
        kcu.table_name as table_name,
        case when (pgc.contype = 'f') then kcu.column_name else ccu.column_name end as column_name, 
        case when (pgc.contype = 'f') then ccu.table_name else (null) end as reference_table,
        case when (pgc.contype = 'f') then ccu.column_name else (null) end as reference_col,
        case when (pgc.contype = 'p') then 'yes' else 'no' end as auto_inc,
        case when (pgc.contype = 'p') then 'no' else 'yes' end as is_nullable,
        'integer' as data_type,
        '0' as numeric_scale,
        '32' as numeric_precision
    from
        pg_constraint as pgc
        join pg_namespace nsp on nsp.oid = pgc.connamespace
        join pg_class cls on pgc.conrelid = cls.oid
        join information_schema.key_column_usage kcu on kcu.constraint_name = pgc.conname
        left join information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu on pgc.conname = ccu.constraint_name 
        and nsp.nspname = ccu.constraint_schema
     union
        select 
            null as constraint_type ,
            table_schema,
            table_name,
            column_name, 
            null as refrence_table, 
            null as refrence_col, 
            'no' as auto_inc,
            is_nullable,
            data_type,
            numeric_scale,
            numeric_precision
        from information_schema.columns cols 
        where 
            table_schema = 'public'
            and concat(table_name, column_name) not in(
                select concat(kcu.table_name, kcu.column_name)
                from
                pg_constraint as pgc
                join pg_namespace nsp on nsp.oid = pgc.connamespace
                join pg_class cls on pgc.conrelid = cls.oid
                join information_schema.key_column_usage kcu on kcu.constraint_name = pgc.conname
                left join information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu on pgc.conname = ccu.constraint_name 
                and nsp.nspname = ccu.constraint_schema
            )
    ) as foo
order by table_name asc, column_name
```

Comment: The where clause `table_name not in (...)` does not work correctly because different tables can have same fields, this leads to less fields. Also `'integer' as data_type` is not always true, an example is an unique email field that is varchar.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer showed unreadable checks column that was compiled or something

[This query](https://database.dev/list-all-constraint) results are readable in all directions

```
select tc.table_schema,
  tc.table_name,
  string_agg(col.column_name, ', ') as columns,
  tc.constraint_name,
  cc.check_clause
from information_schema.table_constraints tc
join information_schema.check_constraints cc
  on tc.constraint_schema = cc.constraint_schema
  and tc.constraint_name = cc.constraint_name
join pg_namespace nsp on nsp.nspname = cc.constraint_schema
join pg_constraint pgc on pgc.conname = cc.constraint_name
  and pgc.connamespace = nsp.oid
  and pgc.contype = 'c'
join information_schema.columns col
  on col.table_schema = tc.table_schema
  and col.table_name = tc.table_name
  and col.ordinal_position = ANY(pgc.conkey)
where tc.constraint_schema not in('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
group by tc.table_schema,
  tc.table_name,
  tc.constraint_name,
  cc.check_clause
order by tc.table_schema,
  tc.table_name;
```