# How to get all create for index and Constraints in PostgreSQL using just SQL

Tags: postgresql

I want a sql to get a list of CREATE of all Index and Constraints in a table 'tablename' just using SQL.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958693

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/214863/how-to-list-all-constraints-of-a-table-in-PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

To show all the indexes of a table, use `pg_indexes`  [PostgreSQL List Indexes](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-indexes/postgresql-list-indexes/)

```
SELECT
    indexname,
    indexdef
FROM
    pg_indexes
WHERE
    tablename = 'table_name';
```

Replace `<table name>` with the name of your table.

Constraints can be retrieved via `pg_catalog.pg_constraint`. [pg_constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/catalog-pg-constraint.html)

```
SELECT con.*
       FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint con
            INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class rel
                       ON rel.oid = con.conrelid
            INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsp
                       ON nsp.oid = connamespace
       WHERE nsp.nspname = '<schema name>'
             AND rel.relname = '<table name>';
```

Replace `<schema name>` with the name of your schema and `<table name>` with the name of your table.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pg_get_indexdef` and `pg_get_constraintdef` [functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-info.html).