# Select FK constraints with ON UPDATE NO ACTION

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, migration, catalogs

We use Postgres 9.5.

Is it possible to modify this script to show the `ON UPDATE` action for each foreign key reference at this table? Or get this values somehow?

```
 SELECT
     tc.table_schema, 
     tc.constraint_name, 
     tc.table_name, 
     kcu.column_name, 
     ccu.table_schema AS foreign_table_schema,
     ccu.table_name AS foreign_table_name,
     ccu.column_name AS foreign_column_name 
 FROM 
     information_schema.table_constraints AS tc 
     JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
       ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
       AND tc.table_schema = kcu.table_schema
     JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
       ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
       AND ccu.table_schema = tc.table_schema
WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the "update action" as in:

```
FOREIGN KEY (foo_id) REFERENCES foo(foo_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
FOREIGN KEY (foo_id) REFERENCES foo(foo_id) ON UPDATE DELETE ON DELETE CASCADE
FOREIGN KEY (foo_id) REFERENCES foo(foo_id) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
```

etc.

.. look in the system catalog table **`pg_constraint`**. It contains the column **`confupdtype`** which holds, [according to the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html):

> Foreign key update action code: `a` = no action, `r` = restrict, `c` = cascade, `n` = set null, `d` = set default

#### Queries

Find all FK constraints with `ON UPDATE NO ACTION` pointing to a given table (***your question in the title***):

```
SELECT conrelid::regclass        AS table_from
     , conname                   AS constraint_name
     , pg_get_constraintdef(oid) AS constraint_def
FROM   pg_constraint
WHERE  contype = 'f'
AND    confupdtype = 'n'
AND    confrelid = 'public.target_table'::regclass  -- target table here
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Inspect all FK constraints in the DB:

```
SELECT conrelid::regclass        AS table_from
     , conname                   AS constraint_name
     , pg_get_constraintdef(oid) AS constraint_def
     , CASE confupdtype
        WHEN 'a' THEN 'NO ACTION'
        WHEN 'r' THEN 'RESTRICT'
        WHEN 'c' THEN 'CASCADE'
        WHEN 'n' THEN 'SET NULL'
        WHEN 'd' THEN 'SET DEFAULT'
        ELSE 'WARNING: unexpected value!'
       END                       AS fk_update_action
FROM   pg_constraint
WHERE  contype = 'f'
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Related:

- [Retrieving all PK and FK](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36979/retrieving-all-pk-and-fk/37068?r=SearchResults#37068)