# Better way to return list of FK "parent" tables?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, postgresql-9.6

Here's what I currently do in Postgres 9.6. (I know it's EOL; that's not my choice to make.)

I don't want the definitions, FK names, or any of the other clutter you get with `\d <table>`.  Just the list of parent tables and column names.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dba.get_fk_parents(_p_table_name TEXT)
    RETURNS TABLE (parent_table TEXT, parent_column NAME)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS
$$
    DECLARE
        cnt INTEGER;
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt
        FROM pg_class
        WHERE relnamespace::regnamespace::text||'.'||relname = _p_table_name;
        IF CNT = 0 THEN
            RETURN QUERY SELECT _p_table_name, 'does not exist'::NAME;
        END IF;
        RETURN QUERY
            select cla2.relnamespace::regnamespace::text||'.'||co.conrelid::regclass::text
                    , att.attname
            from pg_constraint co
                inner join pg_class cla1
                    on co.confrelid = cla1.oid
                inner join pg_class cla2
                    on co.conrelid = cla2.oid
                inner join pg_attribute att
                    on co.conrelid = att.attrelid
            where co.contype = 'f'
                and cla1.relnamespace::regnamespace::text||'.'||cla1.relname = _p_table_name
                and co.conkey[1] = att.attnum
            order by 1;
    END;
$$;
```

Call:

```
select * from dba.get_fk_parents( 'tms.transaction');
          parent_table          |   parent_column   
--------------------------------+-------------------
 cds.cdstransaction             | cdstransaction_id
 cds.rel_x937bundle_transaction | transaction_id
 tms.document                   | transaction_id
 tms.payment                    | transaction_id
 tms.sub_transaction            | transaction_id
(5 rows)


select * from dba.get_fk_parents( 'tms.operator');
 parent_table | parent_column 
--------------+---------------
(0 rows)


select * from dba.get_fk_parents( 'tms.foo');
 parent_table | parent_column  
--------------+----------------
 tms.foo      | does not exist
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 3):

> Just the list of parent tables and column names.

#### "Children"

I fixed the terminology. What you display are the tables **referencing** the input table. So **"children"**, not **"parents"**.

You can trim some clutter. What remains fits into a plain SQL function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_fk_children(_tbl regclass)
  RETURNS TABLE (child_table text, child_columns name[])
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE STRICT AS
$func$
SELECT co.conrelid::regclass::text, array_agg(att.attname)
FROM   pg_constraint co
JOIN   pg_attribute  att ON co.conrelid = att.attrelid
WHERE  co.contype = 'f'
AND    co.confrelid = _tbl
AND    att.attnum = ANY(co.conkey)
GROUP  BY co.conrelid
ORDER  BY 1
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM dba.get_fk_children('tms.transaction');  -- optionally schema-qualified!
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MBNF3BCL)

Adding the column names of referenced parent columns would seem useful, not "clutter". But I went with your displayed format.

There are also multicolumn FK constraints. So this function aggregates all FK columns and returns an **array** of column names.

Works in Postgres 9.6 just as well as Postgres 16.

Passing [`regclass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html#DATATYPE-OID-TABLE) instead of `text`, as this is more convenient. **You can still schema-qualify the input table name.** That's always best to be sure.

The function raises an **exception** for non-existent object names before even calling the function because the cast in the call fails. Existing objects in [`pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html) that are not tables still pass. You may or may not want to raise an error for those, too. Either way, only actual tables can have FK constraints.

Output table names are double-quoted where necessary, and schema-qualified where the current `search_path` requires it. That's built into the cast from `regclass` to `text`.

You can set an empty `search_path` to **force schema-qualified output table names**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_fk_children_schema_qualified(_tbl regclass)
  RETURNS TABLE (child_table text, child_columns name[])
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE STRICT SET search_path = '' AS  -- !!!
-- same function body as above
```

Related:

- [Retrieving all PK and FK](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36979/retrieving-all-pk-and-fk/37068#37068)

#### "Parents"

To actually list "parents":

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_fk_parents(_tbl regclass)
  RETURNS TABLE (parent_table text, parent_columns name[])
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE STRICT AS
$func$
SELECT co.confrelid::regclass::text, array_agg(att.attname)
FROM   pg_constraint co
JOIN   pg_attribute  att ON co.confrelid = att.attrelid
WHERE  co.contype = 'f'
AND    co.conrelid = _tbl
AND    att.attnum = ANY(co.confkey)
GROUP  BY co.confrelid
ORDER  BY 1
$func$;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MBNF3BCL)

Adding the column names of referencing child columns would seem useful, not "clutter".

Comment: It did not throw an exception when passing a non-existent table name; it just returned "(0 rows)".  Also, I don't want it to use the search path.  That's why I specified the schema name.

Comment: @RonJohn: It certainly throws an exception for non-existent object names. Also, you do not *have* to rely on the `search_path`. (Strictly speaking, it is always "used".) Consider clarifications above.

Comment: I would not have copied the "(0 rows)" from psql terminal output if it had thrown an error.

Comment: Have a look at the added fiddle. The remaining explanation is that you entered the name of an index, sequence, view, materialized view, composite type, or toast table. Or there is still confusion about the direction of FK constraints. Read the details in my answer.

Comment: It throws an error **when arrays used**, not when referencing a single column.

Comment: @RonJohn: Sorry, I don't understand your last comment.